# How are Fetch Metadata Request Headers more secure than the Referer Header?

Tags: web-browser, csrf

https://www.w3.org/TR/fetch-metadata/ for reference.

It seems like this is a simplified version of referer headers. Is the only advantage backend developer usability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems like this is a simplified version of referer headers

One cannot get the information in Sec-Fetch-Dest, Sec-Fetch-Mode or Sec-Fetch-User from the Referer. These headers provide useful details about the context of the request which were not available before.

And while Sec-Fetch-site provides information which could also be obtained from the Referer, the Referer could be suppressed by the user or site. Moreover it provides the relationship between origin and destination from the perspective of the browser which is more reliable then comparing Referer and current URL on the server side to guess what kind of relationship this might mean for the browser its same origin policy and cookie policy.